# what happened in Linux after write (2) to stdout until the string is showed on tty or virtual tty?

Tags: c, linux

I'm wondering what happened after system call write (2) to stdout until the string is showed on tty or virtual tty? in another word, how do the kernel receive the system call and finally let VGA driver read and render it? what functions are called in this control flow?

I'm so sorry that I'm a newbie on asking questions, I'd appreciate if you could tell me **how to narrow my topic**, thanks.

I've had a really simple understanding about that:

1. the string is transfered from user space to kernel space from system call write (2).
2. kernel handle it, put the string in a place in the memory which VGA or something else could read it.(**this is the part I really want to know details**)
3. the VGA driver read that memory and render it on tty.

Can anybody help me? it's better if you could give the function name in the kernel which I could check in the LXR.

Comment: You want debug at kernel level. It is not a so easy task. But the most relevant point is that your simplification is too...simplified! That is not the flow to show something on the screen, it involves files, streams, kernel drivers, cards drivers, etc...

Comment: Would you settle for a pony?

Comment: @Frankie_C, hi, yes, I want to track what happens down through the flow, sorry that I don't know much about the kernel, but if somebody could give me some hint on how to explore it is also good to me, I can use kgdb to debug the kernel by myself but it may take so much time so I prefer to get answer from here.

Comment: @Boluny It is very hard not only for the complexity, but also for the concurrency of tasks. Before to afford such job you need to know much more about Linux internals and how it works. I suggest you to begin to read around and to have a look at sources (start googling for "linux innternals").

Answer (score 5):

From what I can tell for a typical case of writing to a virtual console (like `/dev/tty1`):

1. `write(2)` is invoked as you describe.
2. `write(2)` delegates (through the [file ops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L459)) to the TTY driver's [tty_write](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L1233).
3. The TTY driver delegates (through the [ldisc ops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tty_ldisc.h#L194)) to the n_tty line discipline's [n_tty_write](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L2362).
4. The n_tty line discipline delegates (through the [tty ops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tty_driver.h#L260)) to the console driver's [con_write](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L2757).
5. The console driver processes the data, interprets control characters and escape sequences, and eventually [redraws the screen](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L656) by calling (through the [consw ops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/console.h#L42)) the VGA console's [vga_con_switch](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/console/vgacon.c#L817).
6. The data is memcpy'd directly to video memory at a location determined by [vgacon_startup](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/console/vgacon.c#L370), e.g. 0xB0000, familiar from [OS independent x86 console rendering](http://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen) literature. The hardware now renders this video memory to screen.

For terminals other than virtual consoles, such serial consoles and `xterm`, step 4+ changes as it uses serial ttys and pseudo ttys instead of the console tty driver.

Comment: hi, big thanks for answering and give me so many hints so I've where to find the code, I will read code according to your guide. thank you so much again!

Comment: Might be worth mentioning something about terminal emulators too.

Answer (score -5):

Here's the GNU version of printf.
printf internally implemented using vfprintf . 
you can see it passing in stdout to vfprintf:

```
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

If you want to dig further on vfprintf .
Here is the source code for vfprintf .
https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c

It will give a clear idea on how vfprintf works .